# How to make a match in an array with links and get the id of the array and the value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pattern-matching

I have a list of links from different servers in an array like this  (`www.google.com/3ijadk382932`) and I need to do a search including `www.google.com/xxxxxxxxx` without having what characters after the bar also and get her position inside the array their ani form to do that in javascript?
Thanks

```
let links = ["https://hil.to/744I35354M0"
    ,"https://filerio.in/nr435345oy8veq"
    ,"https://mirrorace.com/m/143538h"
    ,"https://download.jheberg.net/9pv2rewt80f4"
    ,"https://www.indishare.me/ys7dwhretewldm5"
    ,"https://www85.zippyshare.com/v/lOtryrx7"
    ,"https://www.sendspace.com/file/8345370j8"
    ,"https://1fichier.com/?rpc2lrandomltgwmx"];
```

I Need to match the filerio link and her position in the array

Something like this Filerio = `{filerio:link,array:[1]}`

Comment: Is this a static list? Will any of the values change?

Comment: Use a regular expression or `split` to get the domain name from the search string. Then loop through the array doing the same thing to each element, and compare it with the domain you got from the search string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var url ="https://filerio.in/"
   var filteredLink = [];
   links.forEach(function(link){ link.indexOf(url) >= 0 
            ? filteredLink.push({"link" : link, position: 
             link.indexOf(url) }) : jQuery.noop()})

   console.log(filteredLink)
```

Comment: It works makes the match but it does not give the id but,I have already solved the code thanks to your apport :)